# jQuery ui sortable triggers click when combined with colorbox

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, click, colorbox, jquery-ui-sortable

I have combined jQuery UI sortable and Jack Moore's [colorbox](http://www.google.no/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.jacklmoore.com%2Fcolorbox%2F&ei=d8SFVKPwLYXoywP8xILwDg&usg=AFQjCNGrj_vvHVrLYoI2BP2WOVW3-haqIA&sig2=mEKCRbjJzA9BGKMuPicOiQ&bvm=bv.80642063,d.bGQ) in the following way.
I display a set of images (e.g., A1, B1 and C1), which I sort as desired using jQuery UI sortable. In addition, I use colorbox to allow clicking on each image, so that an image gallery lighbox is launched, showing extra images associated to each of the initially shown images. So, for example, if I click on image A1 I get a lightbox showing images A1, A2 and A3. This works really great:

```
    HTML code:
    <ul class="sortable">
            <li class="ui-state-default">
                <a clas="p1gallery" href="A1_url"><img src="A1_url"></a>
            </li>
            <li class="ui-state-default">
                <a class="p2gallery" href="B1_url"><img src="B1_url"></a>
            </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Hidden links to tell colorbox what images should use -->
    <table>
      <tbody>
            <tr class="even">
                <td>
                  <a class="p1gallery" href="A2_url"></a>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <a class="p2gallery" href="B2_url"></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    Javascript code:
    $(function() {
       $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    });
    jQuery('a.p1gallery').colorbox({rel:'p1gallery', transition:"none"});
    jQuery('a.p2gallery').colorbox({rel:'p2gallery', transition:"none"});
```

The problem is I do not want the colorbox's gallery to include the images that can be sorted (i.e., A1, B1 and C1). So if I click on image A1, the gallery shuld only show images A2 and A3. For that I have done as explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21392774/additional-colorbox-text-link-to-slideshow) to launch colorbox's lightbox "manually":

```
    HTML code:
    <!-- Note that now, these links do not have a class defined, so the images the piont to are not bound by colorbox -->
    <ul class="sortable">
            <li class="ui-state-default">
                <a id="openGallery-p1" href="A1_url"><img src="A1_url"></a>
            </li>
            <li class="ui-state-default">
                <a id="openGallery-p2" href="B1_url"><img src="B1_url"></a>
            </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Hidden links to tell colorbox what images should use -->
    <table>
      <tbody>
            <tr class="even">
                <td>
                  <a class="p1gallery" href="A2_url"></a>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <a class="p2gallery" href="B2_url"></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    Javascript code:
    $(function() {
       $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    });
    var $p1gallery = $('a.p1gallery').colorbox({rel:'p1gallery', transition:"none"});
    $("a#openGallery-p1").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $p1gallery.eq(0).click();
    });
    var $p2gallery = $('a.p2gallery').colorbox({rel:'p2gallery', transition:"none"});
    $("a#openGallery-p2").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $p2gallery.eq(0).click();
    });
```

Unfortunately, with the last code the galleries work as expected (i.e., images A1,.. are not shown) when I click on the images. I can also sort the images as expected. But when I drag an image and I drop it, the colorbox's gallery for that image is launched! I have tried to find some information on how to prevent a "click" event to be triggered after dropping the image, but I have to admit I am a newbie and I do not know how I should modify the code to launch the colorbox's gallery (see above) and/or jQuery's UI sortable code to achieve that. Any help would be extremely appreciated.

EDIT: See demo showing the problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/nwe4pjtb/1/
I have now seen the problem exists when using Firefox 33.1. It works fine in Chrome 39.0.2171.71 m

Comment: Why am I not seeing any `<table>` tags in there..? Can you provide an online demo reproducing this..?

Comment: The mising <table> was my mistake.I have now created an online demo (see the edit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! I specified the

```
clone: "helper"
```

option for sortable, as recommended in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/947195/jquery-ui-sortable-how-can-i-cancel-the-click-event-on-an-item-thats-dragged) and it worked. See the demo with the fix [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nwe4pjtb/2/)